# Script to read contents from the user

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

How to write a shell script which creates a file

```
    echo "Enter the file you want to create"
    read a
    touch $a
```

And adds content to the created file 'a'

```
echo "Enter the contents to your $a file:"
cat > $a << 'EOF'
EOF
```

The above one is not the right way, what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there.  This will do what you ask:

```
echo "Enter the file you want to create"
read a
echo "Enter the contents to your $a file (press ctrl-D when done):"
cat >"$a"
```

#### Discussion

```
touch $a
```

It is not necessary to touch the file.  The `cat` statement will create it regardless.

Also, because file names can include whitespace, it is best to put inside double-quotes any shell variable containing a file name.  This prevents word splitting.

```
cat > $a << 'EOF'
EOF
```

The construct `<< 'EOF'` tells the shell to read from a *here document*.  This is what you use if you have text in your shell script that you want to use as input.  You don't.  You want instead to read input from the user.  Thus the above two lines can be simply replaced with `cat >"$a"` .

Answer (score 1):

You can ask then proceed with a simple echo:

```
echo "Enter the file you want to create"
read file
echo "Enter the contents to your $a file:"
read content

echo "$content" > "$file"
```